# Issue with imaplib and appending messages with flags

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

new issue with this library that is day-per-day confusing me...

I wish to retrieve messages from auth host1 and append them to auth host2 with all flags.

So:

```
flags = authconnection.fetch(idOne, '(FLAGS)')[1]
flags = ParseFlags(flags[0])
authconnection1.append(folder, flags, date, msg[1][0][1])
```

It works fine when I fetch messages with only one flags, but when I try to append a message with two or more flags (listed in a tuple as requested) I got this error.

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Example code:
**WITH ERROR**

```
connection1.append('INBOX', ('\SEEN', '\Answered'), date, msg[1][0][1])
```

Example code **WITHOUT GETTING ERROR AND THIS WORK FINE**

```
connection1.append('INBOX', ('\SEEN',), date, msg[1][0][1])
('OK', ['[APPENDUID 1 3052] APPEND completed'])
```

Any idea?

Thanks

**RESOLVED**

You have to write a function to parse flag after
    flags = ParseFlags(flags[0])
because this function returns a tuple, but in append command you have to pass a string

```
current = ""
if flags != ():
    for flag in flags:
        current = current + ' ' + flag
        current = current.strip()
if current == "":
    return None
else:
    return current
```

Comment: did you have any luck with this? same issue here...

Comment: Yes you have to write a function to parse flag afterflags = ParseFlags(flags[0])

Comment: Roll back your edit and post that as an answer instead, then mark your answer as accepted. That way, this question no longer shows up as unresolved. Thanks.

Comment: i just did `flag_str = " ".join(flags)` and i didn't have any issues with ~2000 emails

Comment: I've answered my question, but I can't mark as accepted. How can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a function to parse flag after `flags = ParseFlags(flags[0])` because this function returns a tuple, but in append command you have to pass a string

```
current = ""
if flags != ():
    for flag in flags:
        current = current + ' ' + flag
        current = current.strip()
if current == "":
    return None
else:
    return current
```

Comment: Why not simply `current = ' '.join(flags)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
flags = list(flag.decode("utf-8") for flag in ParseFlags(msg.get("flags")))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. 
Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. 
You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).